# derived tree from cfg

Tags: discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, regular-expressions

I need to draw the derived tree for $1-2-(3-4)*5*6$ from the grammar below.
 I want to know how many possibility derived tree are there from this grammar.

$$\begin{align}V_n&=\{expr,term,factor,number\}\\
V_t&= \{(,),-,*,0...9\}\\
P&=\left \{
\begin{aligned}
expr&\to expr-expr\;\mid\;term\\
term&\to term*factor\;\mid\;factor\\
factor&\to number \;\mid\; (expr) \\
number&\to 0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
\end{aligned}
\right \}\\
S&=expr
\end{align}
$$

The possbilities that I can find are:

$$(1-2)-(((3-4)*5)*6)\\
1-(2-( ((3-4)*5)  *6))$$

Are there other possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

The ambiguity in your grammar is limited to the production $expr\to expr - expr$; the production for multiplication is unambiguously left-associative. So in this particular case, there are only two possible parses, as you have indicated.

Comment: thankyou , for this kind of problem, to see the total derived tree, i need to derive  it from the first production rule as it has the highest precedence(?)  and also i need to find both right and left associative?

Comment: @fiksx: CFG productions don't have precedences, You start with the start symbol (whatever $S$ is), and proceed in any way that works. Associativity is just a way of looking at how the grammar parses; you can say that a production for an operator produces a left-associative parse if it unambiguously forces grouping on the right (as your grammar does for $*$). But the derivations are always what the grammar says are possible; it's a simple game of textual substitution.